# Is Spring Integration a good fit for load balancing across multiple jvms?

Tags: spring-integration

We have a POC using Spring Core whose work is essentially determined by two application properties read from a file. We can scale this out by spinning up additional jvms (running same code base) and assigning different property values to each jvm so that they don't interfere with each other. This works to an extent, but I would like to make it more dynamic. I can kind of see how SI might be a fit here. I think I could create one application that queries the DB and figures out the work parameters and sends those out to the available instances of our application in kind of a round-robin fashion. But am having trouble seeing how to implement it technically.  All the applications are running on the same machine, so they have the same IP address. Also, they are not web apps. Would I need to use JMS (which I am not familiar with) or can SI handle this?

Comment: I see no such issue with the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use JMS, RabbitMQ, Redis, or any number of outbound endpoints to distribute the work.

Let's say you choose to use simple rmi or TCP/UDP; you can simply have a number of outbound endpoints subscribed to the routing channel and SI will round robin the requests (by default).

This would be statically configured though. You would need a little glue if you want to dynamically change the number of servers without using a broker such as JMS or RabbitMQ.

The [dynamic FTP sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/advanced/dynamic-ftp) illustrates a technique of adding new destinations (in that case ftp servers) dynamically.

Comment: Thanks Gary, you got me headed in the right direction. I have small POC using Rmi started now with just a single node, but will be adding more to see how the round-robin works.